# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' ;installed in multiple location

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

try:
    source = requests.get('https://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/Hotels-g294265-Singapore-Hotels.html')
    source.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup)

    hotel = soup.find('div', class_="prw_rup prw_meta_hsx_responsive_listing ui_section listItem")

    print(hotel)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

```
PS C:\Users\keeha\PycharmProjects\INF1002_Draft> py main1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\keeha\PycharmProjects\INF1002_Draft\main1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
PS C:\Users\keeha\PycharmProjects\INF1002_Draft> cd C:\Users\keeha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts          
PS C:\Users\keeha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts> .\pip install requests                                                     
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\keeha\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\keeha\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in c:\users\keeha\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\keeha\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2022.9.24)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\keeha\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests) (1.26.12)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\keeha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
PS C:\Users\keeha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts> cd c:\users\keeha\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages
PS C:\users\keeha\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages> py C:\Users\keeha\PycharmProjects\INF1002_Draft\main1.py                   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\keeha\PycharmProjects\INF1002_Draft\main1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
PS C:\users\keeha\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages>
```

I am trying to webscrape but it keep popping up the NoModuleFoundError while I have installed it in both my python and pycharm and I can find it in my settings. Please also a look at this link "i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/2e/6c/…" and see if you can notice anything that might cause the error?

Answer (score 0):

To install requests module on Debian/Ubuntu for Python 2:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-requests
```

And for Python 3 the command is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-requests
```

**Windows**

Use

> pip install requests

(or

> pip3 install requests for python3)

if you have pip installed and Pip.exe added to the Path Environment Variable. If pip is installed but not in your path you can use python -m pip install requests (or python3 -m pip install requests for python3)

Alternatively from a cmd prompt, use > Path\easy_install.exe requests, where Path is your Python*\Scripts folder, if it was installed. (For example: C:\Python32\Scripts)

If you manually want to add a library to a windows machine, you can download the compressed library, uncompress it, and then place it into the Lib\site-packages folder of your python path. (For example: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages)

Comment: Hi Gajanan, thanks for your assistance. I used the Pip to download and it still shows "Requirement already satisfied". May you look at this link "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/2e/6c/e52e6ccdc53d838735ba3d59c37a56a2.jpg" and see if you can notice any thing that might cause the error?